# Which form should be used, why and when?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Using generics in typescript I can define a generic function like this:

**Option 1**

```
declare function foo1<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): T[K] {
  return obj[key];
}
```

Or I can skip the second type and declare a function this way.

**Option 2:**

```
declare function foo2<T>(obj: T, key: keyof T): T[keyof T] {
  return obj[key];
}
```

Now I can invoke both of these functions the same way but I wonder if one of these options have any advantage over the other?

Which one should I use and why? Which one is more idiomatic TS, if there is such a thing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference in a return type.

```js
function foo1<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): T[K] {
  return obj[key];
}

function foo2<T>(obj: T, key: keyof T): T[keyof T] {
  return obj[key];
}

const result1 = foo1({ a: 1, b: 'str' }, 'a') // number

const result2 = foo2({ a: 1, b: 'str' }, 'a') // string | number
```

In first scenario, TS is able to  bind object key and value. Hence - TS is able to infer exact type of value by the key - `number`.

In the second scenario TS is aware that `a` is allowed but it is unable to infer exact type of `a` value. Hence, TS returns a union of all possible cases.

Try to hover the mouse over `foo1`, you will see that second generic argument is infered as `a`

If you want to narrow return type - use option 1.

Most of the time you don't need to explicitly define return types. TS should infer them automagically

**how come TS is able to bind the key to a value in the fist case ?**

First of all you definitely need to read [Generic Functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#generic-functions) from the doc.

> In TypeScript, generics are used when we want to describe a correspondence between two values.

> In TypeScript, generics are used when we want to describe a correspondence between two values. We do this by declaring a type parameter in the function signature

Also, you need to read [Inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#inference) section.

You can also read [this](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments) article from my blog

Let's go back to you function:

```js
function foo<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): T[K] {
    return obj[key];
}

const result = foo({ a: 1 }, 'a')
```

Please hover on `foo`:
[image]

As you might have noticed,`T` is infered to `{a: number;}` and `K` is infered to `a`.
So we have next type:

```js
type Infered_T = {
    a: number;
}

type Infered_K = 'a'

type Result = Infered_T[Infered_K] // number
```

Please don't forget that square bracket notation works same as in regular js.
Hence above  code is similar to this code in plain js:

```js
const Infered_T = {
    a: 42,
}

const Infered_K = 'a'

const Result = Infered_T[Infered_K] // number
```

Comment: bravo! I completely missed the return type when I spent bloody 30 min looking through these two signatures back and forth. Do you know, by any chance how come TS is able to bind the key to a value in the fist case? I mean to me there is no difference if the second argument is of type "keyof T" or of type "K extends keyof T". I ask, because I can drop the return type signature in declaration but TS is still able to narrow the return type in the first case. Any link I can read on some details of how it works?